# Show real-time progress with GNU Parallel and Stata

Tags: bash, stata, gnu-parallel

I'm using GNU parallel to run a Stata `do` file for many different data sets.

I have a Bash script that contains the following:

```
parallel -a arguments.txt -j 3 stata -b do $dofileloc {}
```

Since the `do` file has several different parts for each dataset, I would like to have the progress shown "real-time" (e.g. display "data loaded for `XYZ`" after a part of the Stata `do` file finishes for a dataset etc.).

So I'd like to redirect messages from Stata to the command line, but I'm having trouble doing this.

If I don't run Stata in batch mode I can see everything, which is a bit messy. I have tried using the `shell` command in Stata but I can't seem to figure out the correct combination.

I would appreciate any tips.

Comment: To my knowledge you can't do that - at least not in real time. Why don't you break up your `do` file in smaller ones for each dataset? Then you could simply include a message in your bash script after each `do` file ends.

Comment: Add a filter at the end maybe? `parallel ... | grep "loaded"`

Comment: Thank you both for the help and apologies for the delay, I've had a lot on my plate and was trying to make some progress with this question before responding. Unfortunately the filter didn't work. The reason why I don't want to break into do files for each dataset is because it is the same code for all of the datasets (there are 30+ of them) which is why I parallelized the process in the first place. I suspect Stata's batch mode might have to do with the problem - any maybe why it's not possible to do this. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
parallel --tag --linebuffer -a arguments.txt -j 3 stata -b do $dofileloc {}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. If I don't use batch mode this does show Stata's output, but I am still not sure how to only show certain output.

Comment: @Paprika What do you use to do that, when not using GNU Parallel?

Comment: @OleTange My understanding is that she only wants to show a specific message to confirm the dataset has loaded, not really channel the entire output. Personally, i think this is not possible. I remember I was trying to do something similar in the past.